# rails 4 button_to selects update no matter what action is specified

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

In my view, I have a button:

```
 <%= button_to 'Check In', { action: "check_in", id: @post.id }, method: "patch", class: "btn btn-primary" %>
```

in my controller, I have a matching method:

```
  def check_in
   respond_to do |format|
    if @post.update(post_params)
     @checkout = Checkout.where(:post_id => @post.id, :author_id => @post.author_id).each do |c|
      c.checked_in = DateTime.now
      c.save
    end
   else
    ...
  end
end
```

I have a matching route, too:

```
  get 'posts/check_in/:id' => 'posts#check_in'
```

But, whenever I click the button, only the update action happens.  From the logs:

Processing by PostsController#update as HTML

**Why is rails choosing the update action instead of check_in?**

Comment: The `patch` method redirects to the update action, remove it or use `get` instead.

Answer (score 0):

The `patch` method redirects to the update action, remove it or use `get` instead.

Comment: I tried both removing patch and replacing it with get, neither worked.

Comment: can you post your routes?

Comment: @meetalexjohnson did you get it to work? Try changing `"patch"` to `:patch`.